# Python Import directive

Tags: python, numpy

1. What I have found is, that if I'm importing packages and I need shortcut I have to write

   ```
   Import numpy.linalg as lg
   ```

   but i dont know what purpose has to write import directive in these format types,

   ```
   import numpy.linalg
   import numpy.numpy.polynomial.polynomial
   ```

   because those directives imports all the `numpy` package at the same way as if i would write just only

   ```
   import numpy
   ```

   at the end the syntax for accessing some functions from let's say polynomial is the same

   ```
   import numpy
   xx = numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polydiv([2],[6])
   ```

   for both cases

   ```
   import numpy.numpy.polynomial.polynomial
   xx = numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polydiv([2],[6])
   ```

   so What is the purpose for this ?
2. Where are stored objects from the NumPy module self? I can find definitions of functions, classes etc.  For every single module in NumPy package in their subfolders, but can't find any files for NumPy itself, for example `numpy.sin()` function.

Comment: It's `import`, not `Import`. Case matters.

Comment: `import numpy as np` has always been sufficient for me.

Comment: The `numpy` `__init__.py` has a dozen `from . Import ...` statements.  That shows what is available with out further import.

Answer (score 3):

Importing a package, such as `numpy`, is not guaranteed to import its submodules and subpackages. `import numpy` happens to load `numpy.linalg` and `numpy.polynomial` due to imports performed by the `numpy` module itself, but this is not a guarantee, and it does not happen for all NumPy submodules. For example,

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.distutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'distutils'
>>> import numpy.distutils
>>> numpy.distutils
<module 'numpy.distutils' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\__init__.pyc'>
```

---

As for the source code of objects in the `numpy` namespace, that varies greatly from object to object, and it can be rather convoluted. For example, `numpy.sin` is a ufunc compiled from C code generated by [`numpy/core/code_generators/generate_umath.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/66873577afe02786fb5484051babd4485c7cb39c/numpy/core/code_generators/generate_umath.py), and that code generator uses components from a bunch of other files.

Comment: But is there any normal `numpy` functionality that requires a separate import?  I've never had to use anything but `import numpy as np`.  `scipy` is organized differently, requiring a separate import for each package, e.g. `from scipy import sparse`.

Comment: @hpaulj: "Normal" NumPy functionality? I think `numpy.__init__` automatically loads all that, but I don't think this is a documented guarantee.

Comment: Can you quote the most relevant import code from __init__?

Comment: @hpaulj: [Here's the section where it goes through all the big NumPy submodules and imports them.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L193)